# how to define filter or expression in string?

Tags: python

If there a way that I can define filter in a variable, then use that variable to filter data frame or filter list?

For example, I can filter the list using code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
f = [i for i in l if i > 3]
f
```

Is there a way that I can define the filter in a variable? (the code below is not working)

```
ft = repr('if i > 3')
f_repr = [i for i in l eval(ft)] 
f_repr
```

Comment: In pandas, there is a similar filter for data frames [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Comment: Does it have to be a string? What about something like `condition = lambda i:  i > 3` such that you can write `[i for i in l if condition(i)]` or `list(filter(condition, l))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using a lambda function.

```
ft=lambda i:i>3
f_repr=[i for i in l if ft(i)]
f_repr
```

Answer (score 2):

You only can do something like:

```
cond = lambda i: i> 3
```

Then:

```
f = [i for i in l if cond(i)]
```

Or:

```
f = list(filter(cond, l))
```

Or for pandas, you can.

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy arrays is quite straightforward

```
f_repr = f[f>3]
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the entire expression a string then `eval` it.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
cond = 'if i > 3'
expr = f'[i for i in l {cond}]'
eval(expr) # => [4, 5]
```

Comment: `eval` is not safe, instead it's bad practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice